# BIND9 ZONES configuration

Tags: dns, bind

I want bind to forward address that have (ico|jpg|png|gif|mp3|js|css|mp4|flv|swf|json) extentions.

Is it possible to do something along those lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Bandrami's answer: a proxy (such as Squid) would fit the bill though.  When used in conjunction with BIND, you can redirect queries for certain content, as well as doing a number of other things (filtering, authentication, etc.).

Comment: Just adding my agreement to joat's addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, those are MIME types, which BIND does not care about whatsoever. In fact, BIND will never even hear about them, because the client application will only ask for the hostname. (For example, when you type http://www.whatever.com/example.jpg in your browser, the browser only asks the nameserver about www.whatever.com, not about the whole URL; other protocols and clients work similarly.)